# python flask template rendering issues

Tags: python, forms, flask

The data should be received from a form and the weather results on the same form.in my terminal, the data is returned but it is not displaying on the web browser. It does not bring any error but does not display it on my browser as expected

```
</head>
<body class="bg-info ">
   <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="mt-5">Weather App</h1>

    <!-- form to take the user input -->
    <form  method="post" action="/">
        <input type="text" id="cityName" name="cityName" placeholder="cityName">
        <button> Find </button>
    </form>
        {% if data %}
    <p>You submitted: {{ data }}</p>
       {% endif %}
</div>
```

this is the Python code

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
from weather import main as get_weather

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    data=None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        city= request.form['cityName']
        data = get_weather(city_name=city)
        
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: When you submit the form and `data = get_weather(city_name=city)` is executed, did you check that data contains real data and is not none? E.g. with `print(data)` before `return render_template(...)`

Comment: yes it is displayed on the terminal but it's on the template where it cannot be rendered

Comment: So the whole `{% if data %}` block ist not shown?

Comment: yes its not shown

Comment: how did you install the weather package? `pip install weather`?

Comment: it is an API.I was trying to integrate the open weather APIs  in flask so it wasn't a package

Comment: Its hard for me to reproduce the error then. What I tested is that when I have `return render_template('index.html', data=city)` the city is shown and this works. Does it work for you too?

Comment: mine does not work for me

Comment: So whatever you insert as data is not shown in your template. Even if you insert something like `data="test string"`?